# How to configure the $http service in Angular depending on itself?

Tags: angularjs, angular-services, angular-http, angular-http-interceptors

I'm trying to configure the `$http` service of Angular, to redirect to an URL when the status code is 403.

No problems so far but the URL to redirect to is coming from the server, through a service which is using `$http` (obiously).

Here's a piece of code:

```
angular
.module('app')
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', 'URLs',
    function($q, Redirect) {
      return {
        request: function(config) {
          return config || $q.when(config);
        },
        responseError: function(response) {
          if(response.status === 403) {
            // redirect to URLs.login
          }
          return $q.reject(response);
        }
      };
    }
  ]);
}])
.factory('URLs', ['$http', function($http) {
  var URLs;
  $http.get('/urls').then(function(response) {
    URLs = response.data;
  });
  return URLs;
}]);
```

This code is creating a circular dependency (error) in Angular.

Is there a way that I can do this, having dynamic URLs that are coming from a server and based on this to redirect the user to one of them when the `response.status` is 403?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`$injector` service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/%24injector) to lazily load the `URLs` service:

```
angular
.module('app')
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', '$injector',
    function($q, $injector) {
      return {
        request: function(config) {
          return config || $q.when(config);
        },
        responseError: function(response) {
          var Redirect = $injector.get('URLs');
          if(response.status === 403) {
            // redirect to URLs.login
          }
          return $q.reject(response);
        }
      };
    }
  ]);
}])
```

You can also break this circular dependency in the `URLs` service by injecting the `$injector` there.

Comment: It doesn't work, in both cases! Angular throws the same `Circular dependency found: URLs <- $http <- $compile`

Comment: Gah. Sorry, the injection wasn't lazy enough: moved it inside the `responseError` function and it works now: http://plnkr.co/edit/gEI8jq5B3xUt7KOxOAf5?p=preview

Comment: Two question though, would you consider this a hack to break the circular dependency? Is there a problem with the "architecture" of the module?

Comment: @ChrisX I don't think this is a hack. I use this technique to push the client logger messages to the server from inside the `$exceptionHandler` and I don't think it is possible to do that without the `$injector` service.

Comment: For this kind of thing I'm throwing the exception from `$exceptionHandler` and a different script (pure JavaScript) catches it using `window.onerror` and logs it to the server.